# Why is my array saving like this (array within an array?)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

I am saving this array but instead of it showing as an array of strings it is showing as an array within an array and I am not sure why?

```
let tmpArray = [] as any;
    for(var i= 0;  i < formData.countriesToField.length; i++)
    {
      tmpArray.push(formData.countriesToField[i].toString());
    }
    tmpArray.push(e);
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      countriesToField: [tmpArray]
      
    });
```

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: `tmpArray` is an array, `[tmpArray]` is therefore an array inside array.

Comment: what is `e` in this snippet?

Answer (score 1):

tmpArray is an array and you closing it inside another array.. use spread syntax or don't create second array..

Change this:

```js
countriesToField: [tmpArray]
```

to this:

```js
countriesToField: tmpArray
// or this:
countriesToField: [...tmpArray]
```